# How to declare generic property of type enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums, model

**I have this Model : Filter**

```
namespace SearchContent.Domains
{
    public class Filter
    {
        public enum FilterName {}; //<================== ???
        public string FilterDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string FilterRemoteName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**And this file : FiltersEnums.cs - list of enums**

```
namespace SearchContent.Domains
{
    public enum filterType
    {
        series, movies, programs, channels
    }

    public enum filterGenre
    {
        action, drama, comedy, horror, documentary, russian
    }
}
```

I need that - "FilterName" can be a filterType or a filterGenre.

How i declear that property "FilterName" ?

Comment: This seems a little odd to do. You can use generics but is that really a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Enum` type:

```
 public Enum FilterName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Enum class:

```
Enum enumGen; //declaring variable with Enum type

enumGen = filterType.series;

//and next you can do for example
enumGen = filterGenre.horror;
```